# Good replacement actuator?

Tags: electrical, hvac, air-conditioning

I have 2 [Belimo actuators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ca4og.jpg)

[image]

that control dampers for A/C ducts in my house that the motor has gone bad on. I can't find much info about the model "LM24-T US" so I think it has been discontinued. I don't see it listed on their [Replacement list](http://www.belimo.us/media/downloads/Technical_Documents/Replacement_Solutions/Discontinued_Belimo_Products_Actuators.pdf) though so I have no idea what to replace it with. Any suggestions?

Comment: A few twisted links, and I found this ebay item   231479690726 which is for BELIMO LM24-T/US USPP LM24TUS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that meets or slightly exceeds the 35 in-lb rating, and matches the 24V spec (though you could check if your system is using AC or DC, and just get one to match your system rather than an AC/DC version.)

I suppose the time should fall in the general range of this one's 80-110 seconds as well, so vents are not slamming open and closed, but I suspect that is somewhat less critical. The power draw should not be too much more than this one at 3VA or you may overload the system that's running it.

Comment: [This one](http://www.supplyhouse.com/Honeywell-ML6161C2007-Non-Spring-Return-Damper-Actuator-90-Second?gclid=CIjdk-e4wsQCFcpZ7AodW2kAmg) seems comparable. Do you think that would work?

Comment: Seems plausible, so so long as your system is 24 VAC. Might want to pull a non-working unit and check the damper shaft size just to be sure it's in the range that fits.

Comment: I ordered a pair from the link I posted. I'll post again with the result just in case anyone else finds this.